# Copy files from Azure SMB share to container automatically

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Every day I recieve files in an Azure SMB share and need to copy them in an Azure blob container. From there they will be loadad into our Snowflake database. I have a python script, which can copy the files, but don't know how to trigger this script automatically each time an new file arrives in the smb share. What is the best way to automatically start such a script?

I tried it with an Azure function app, but can't connect it with a file event.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419909/is-a-question-asking-for-good-ways-to-do-something-really-opinion-based